# Generate random file in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to test a code that I made with randomly generated files with certain extensions(so that I  can check validation always works), I've searched for this, but could only find something about faker, it generates random data, but I am looking to generate files in Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this very thing using PHP alone.

Make an array of names of files manually or see [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generating-random-string-using-php/) to generate a random string.

Then define an array of extensions that you want to test against.

And then very easily you can merge the two above to have random files with certain extensions.

If you still have any doubts please let me know and I'll update my answer accordingly.